# KeyboardAvoidingView not pushing up TextInput on keyboard show

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a view combining a `FlatList` with a `View` containing `TextInput`. I want the `View` containing the `TextInput` to sit at the bottom of the screen, with the `FlatList` occupying the remainder of the screen space. When you tap to enter text in the `TextInput`, I'd like the view to move upwards with the keyboard and overlap the `FlatList` contents - the sort of behaviour you'd usually see in a messaging screen on an app.

I've got the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, SafeAreaView, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

function Messages() {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: "center",
            }}
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={[1, 2, 3]}
                    renderItem={() => <Text>test</Text>}
                />
                <View style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                }}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{
                            height: "auto",
                            margin: 5,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            padding: 5,
                            flex: 1,
                        }}
                    />
                    <Icon
                        name={"send"}
                        size={25}
                    />
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}

export default Messages;
```

However, the `TextInput` seems to always hide behind the keyboard rather than move with the keyboard. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `SafeAreaView`. You have placed it inside of your `KeyboardAvoidingView`. Ideally, all of your components must be nested inside of `SafeAreaView` and not the other way around.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}> // Keep it as parent
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      >
        <FlatList data={[1, 2, 3]} renderItem={() => <Text>test</Text>} />
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            style={{
              height: "auto",
              margin: 5,
              borderWidth: 1,
              padding: 5,
              flex: 1,
            }}
          />
          <Icon name={"send"} size={25} />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The rest of your code is fine.
Here's the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/-54HThEmc).

Comment: Interesting that it works on Expo but not on my Xcode simulator. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @CheesyChameleon What is your react-native version?

Comment: Seems to be v0.72.4

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, SafeAreaView, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

function Messages() {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        >
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    {/* FlatList contents */}
                    {Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, index) => (
                        <Text key={index}>Item {index}</Text>
                    ))}

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={{
                                height: "auto",
                                margin: 5,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                padding: 5,
                                flex: 1,
                            }}
                        />
                        <Icon name={"send"} size={25} />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}

export default Messages;
```